# Add new record to subform with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

A subform is populated by fields from a combo box, and the record saves as expected. With click on next record in the combo box, the record saved earlier is overwritten. I've tried the following `on current` in the main form and similar code but nothing works. It still wants to overwrite a previously saved record. Any suggestions?

```
Me![Forms![frmAccount]![subAccount].SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNext, Offset:=1
```

The code in the following post did not work either?
[Making "DoCmd.GoToRecord" function work on a subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347503/making-docmd-gotorecord-function-work-on-a-subform)

Comment: Your code doesn't match the code in the linked question.  Why the difference?

Comment: Also, your question is a bit unclear.  What do you mean by "When I click on the next record in the combobox?"  Going to the next record in a combobox?  I'm not sure what this means.  A combobox generally represents one field in a record, not the next record...

Comment: Records in the combo box can be selected, so I select one, it populates the fields in the subform and I save it. Then I repeat the process selecting an different record in the combo box and it populates the same fields in the subform (a datasheet format). I have to redirect focus to a line for a new record in order to not overwrite a previously saved record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `On Change` on combo box field in main form and enter:

```
subFormname.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

I kept trying and came up with this syntax. Let me know if you have anything better.