# "The Object [Form name] isn't open" Access Navigation tab Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am referencing a FORM from navigation tab but it shows error that the form is not open even though its already open. Please see the image below. For Proof see debug section that the form is open.

[image: My Code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making "DoCmd.GoToRecord" function work on a subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347503/making-docmd-gotorecord-function-work-on-a-subform)

Comment: A different way of navigation is with `Form.RecordsetClone.FindFirst` and Bookmarks. See http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/bookmarks-and-recordset-clones.html